# What's the correct title for someone doing the layout, additional content, and getting agreements from the writers and artists?

Tags: publishing, anthologies

I recently participated in an ekphrastic event where a number of poets wrote poems inspired by paintings from a couple of artists. We've decided to create an anthology based on the paintings and poems and my fledgling small press will be the publisher. I'm doing the layout, additional content, getting agreements from the writers and artists, etc.

How would I list myself on the book? I'm not really editing the pieces, so I don't think "Editor" works. I'm not really compiling the collection — that is already determined by the folks who wrote for the event. Do I even list myself as something or do I just use the name of the press?

Comment: You write *my fledgling small press will be the publisher* doesn't that make you the *publisher*?  Failing that, what about *ekphrastician*?  *ekphrastic* is such a lovely word (I have no idea what its dictionary definition might be, kinda get the meaning from your post) that it would be a shame not to use it again.

Comment: Yes, the press will be the publisher. I'm thinking about how most anthologies have someone editing them. But I guess it makes sense to not have a person's name on this but just have the press name. Ekphrastic is essentially when one piece of artwork/writing is inspired by one from a different medium. So writing a poem or a piece of music inspired by a painting would make it an ekphrastic poem or song.

Comment: If you were only doing the layout, you might be a "layout editor".
Maybe as the person facilitating the making of the book, you could be considered the "producer"?

Answer (score 1):

I think the more important tasks here are layout and coordination with writers and artists. Considering that the following may be suitable:

**Layout Editor & Contributors Coordinator**

Comment: Thanks! Those are good titles, wish I'd had them sooner. I just went with "Edited by". FWIW the book was completed and published in July. :-)